# No apt pip-is-pip3 package

Tags: apt, python

Ubuntu 20.04 dropped python2 and you can make the `python` command call the installed python 3.x by

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Additionally I installed

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Now I can call `python` (→ Python 3.8.2), but for pip I need to append the `3`.
An aquivalent pip-is-pip3 package seems not to be available.

What is the recommended way to let `pip` work as `pip3`?

Make a softlink?
Or never do it, but `venv` and only `pip` there?

Comment: Renaming python3-related commands and applications to drop the "3" does appeal to some folks. However, the Python Project upstream, Debian packagers, and Ubuntu  developers all kept the "3" for some good reasons. Consider emulating them.. You can rename anything you wish, but you risk "file-not-found" errors at unexpected times, and confusion when you discuss the problem with anybody.

Comment: I'm wondering why this does not hold for ``python``?  The point is the different approach, python for python3 is fine, pip for pip3 not (no python2 anymore and deprecated for longer).

Comment: Python-for-Python3 is NOT fine in 2020. It is not done in any supported release of Ubuntu, and is not under consideration by the Ubuntu developers.

Comment: I see, so this was my wrong assumption. Thanks. This plus the hint 'always venv' I'd accept as answer.

Comment: This question has answers to this question, including options specific to Debian/Ubuntu: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an expert, but I think you can add this to the end of your .bashrc file in your home directory

```bsh
alias pip=pip3
```

You can also configure `update-alternatives` by running this (again, might be different) :

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1
```

If that doesn't work, well, I must warn you, ***this may be dangerous***, but you can copy the content of `/usr/bin/pip3` and paste it into `/usr/bin/pip`

Doing so *should* make it so when you run pip, it will run pip3 intstead.

Another ***dangerous*** way of doing things is just editing the content of `/usr/bin/pip` to just have it run

```
#!/bin/bash
pip3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I prefer to link the existing one(s) as hinted by @justfortherec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip

Comment: I just transfered it into an anwser format on this post, to make other users not have to click on the link. Also, the dangerous ways were original by me (although nobody should *need* to use them)